# Android: How do I change the style of a RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ListFragment that produces a list of 'cards' onscreen that look like this:

[app screen mockup](http://addelement.com/android-screen-states.png)

The ListFragment uses a RelativeLayout to render each card:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        style="@style/CardDefault">

        ... many other elements here

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The full XML for the card (above) is actually very verbose, as there are many more items in the card that are not in the screenshot. I omitted the extra stuff, because it's lengthy.

The style for card is as follows:

```
<style name="Card">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/card</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/card_text_default</item> 
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:padding">16dp</item>
</style>
```

The default color of a card is the blue color, shown on top in the screenshot I linked to above. Once a card is completed, it gets the green style - the bottom card in the above screenshot.

I'd like to simply replace the blue style (shown above) with a green one. The style switch would happen  when the view first loads - it's not something that would happen while the user is viewing this screen.

I've been playing around with different ways to do this, but can't seem to figure out what the best practice is.

It seems wasteful to have a completely different layout xml file merely to reference a different style attribute. Especially, when my layout xml file is very verbose, as I mentioned.

What's the best way for me to change the style on this Relativelayout I have?

Edit - 01/27

I've learned some more about Android, and have some more detail. I'd like to do something like the following code shows - the comments within the if blocks are pseudocode:

```
private class PrescriptionCardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Prescription> {
        public PrescriptionCardAdapter(List<Prescription> prescriptions) {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.activity_fragment, prescriptions);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (null == convertView) {
                if (cardState == "complete") {
                    // apply the COMPLETE theme or style to this specific view
                    convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.prescription_card, null);
                }
                else if (cardState == "overdue") {
                    // apply the OVERDUE theme or style to this specific view
                    convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.prescription_card, null);
                }
                else {
                    // apply the DEFAULT theme or style to this specific view
                    convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.prescription_card, null);
                }

            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can apply a theme or a style to my views as they inflate them? Greg, could I do something with AttributeSets in the above code?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should redefine your point of view: `"There is no setStyle() method because you can't change the style after the view is initialized."` https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/iMU7jHkKdQ0 | You should search for dynamically change TextColor and Background, not the Style of your view.

Comment: styles are bound in the constructor based on `View(Context, AttributeSet)` and `View(Context, AttributeSet, int defAttr)` The attribute is parsed there from the XML and after the constructor all the xml data is gone

Comment: Fllo, thanks for the link. It's good to have that link you shared as a resource in case that turns out to be the best way for me to implement.

Comment: Greg, I think what you mentioned might be a good fit. I need to change the style not at runtime, but when the screen first renders. Do you have any further examples of that technique? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. I updated my original post, above, to include some more information. Greg, if you're still out there, I wonder if I could use the AttributeSet technique you mentioned in the code I included in my update?  Any help appreciated.